# How to detect if a Facebook access token has been refreshed?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-access-token

in my app I need to detect if an access token has been refreshed so that i can update my API with the new token.

I am having trouble trying to figure out the best way to approach this since the Facebook SDK automatically caches the access token - currently I am comparing the old token (which i save to NSUserDefaults) with the accessToken of the activeSession's accessTokenData.

If the tokens are different I send update my api with the newer token.

here is my code within `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
  NSString *newToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
  NSString *oldToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"accessToken"];

  if (oldToken) {
        if ([newToken isEqualToString:oldToken]) {
            NSLog(@"token was not refreshed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"token was refreshed");
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:newToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
            /* update API with new token*/
        }
    } else+
    {
        //if no token exists, set one with the current token
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:newToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
    }
```

I have to admit it's really hacky, but I cant seem to find a way around it. Is there any better way of approaching it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'refreshed'? When you get an access token from the login flow it'll always be the newest one available to you via the at flow - the string itself may not change even if the expiry time gets bumped to reflect the user's continuing use of your app

Comment: hmm, i was under the assumption that access tokens get renewed when they expire @Igy

Comment: @Igy so are you saying that if the user never logs out, there is no chance of the access token from expiring?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing - if you're using the sample code with the iOS SDK it'll refresh the the token automatically in FBSession adn give you one valid until 'time user last opened your app' + token expiry (probably 1-2 hours), but the token string itself may or may not change